# How to write a switch statement that compares multiple variables?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in JS, I was hoping this code worked but it doesn’t, what would be an alternative way of accomplishing the result I'm expecting here? basically want to return something based on the combination of 3 variables/arguments. (btw, in some case statements I'm not mentioning the 'roomSize' value because I'm expecting the code to know that it's the same as the original value)

```
const roombaMovement = (direction , initialRoombaLocation, roomSize) => {
    const roombaLocation = initialRoombaLocation
    let wallHit = 0;
    switch (roombaLocation && direction && roomSize) {
      case [4,0] && "S" && [4,0]:
        wallHit +=1;
        break;
      case [0,0] && "W":
        wallHit +=1;
        break;
      case [1,0] && "S":
        wallHit +=1;
        break;
      case [0,1] && "W":
        wallHit +=1;
        break;
      default:
    }
    return wallHit;
  }
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn’t have any constructs that work like that, so for actual alternatives you’ll have to consider the big picture. What is the function supposed to do? Check for the walls of a room? (I would assume that, but it’s a bit unclear why it checks for an exact value of `roomSize` or what the significance of 1 is in the `[1, 0]` and `[0, 1]` cases.)

Comment: There's always good old "if-then-else" instead of switch.

Comment: oh.. It's supposed to let me know if the Roomba vacuum cleaner hits a wall (wallHit), based on the dimensions of a room(roomSize) and based on the driving instruction('direction')

Comment: Changing this to the equivalent solution using multiple if/else statements is not the best solution. You should write a more general solution such as `if row==0 && direction=="S"` then you'll hit a wall. If row==max_row-1 and direction="N" then you'll hit a wall.

Comment: Unfortunately not available as a language-level feature in JS, but consider using a pattern-matching library such as [tailored](https://github.com/elixirscript/tailored).

Comment: logically, what you wrote doesn't make much sense. you have 4 different checks and every one of the results in the exact same result. why would you want 4 different case statements to all do the same thing? answer: you wouldn't. try just doing a simple if/then statement and go from there.

Comment: Ah I see thanks for all your insights everyone  I'll try out your suggestions and report back.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `switch` for this - it's quite verbose *and* will be tedious to get the syntax to work properly for the logic you want. Since all the resulting statements to execute are the same (increment `wallHit`), all you need is a single (but large) `if` statement:

```
const arrsEqual = (a, b) => a.length === b.length && a.every((num, i) => num === b[i]);
const roombaMovement = (direction , initialRoombaLocation, roomSize) => {
  const roombaLocation = initialRoombaLocation
  let wallHit = 0;
  if (
    (direction === 'S' && arrsEqual(roombaLocation, [4, 0]) && arrsEqual(roomSize, [4, 0])) ||
    (direction === 'W' && arrsEqual(roombaLocation, [0, 0])) ||
    (direction === 'S' && arrsEqual(roombaLocation, [1, 0])) ||
    (direction === 'W' && arrsEqual(roombaLocation, [0, 1]))
  ) {
    wallHit +=1;
  }
  return wallHit;
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks so much CertainPerformance, I remember you from my previous question as well 

Comment: Ok so I edited my code to this but the wallHits are not being updated and my linter is saying "no-mixed-operators: Unexpected mix of && and ||"
```const roombaMovement = (direction , roombaLocation, roomSize) => {
    let wallHit = 0;
    const x = roombaLocation[0]
    const y = roombaLocation[1]
    const max_x = roomSize[0]
    const max_y = roomSize[1]

    if (
      x === 0 && direction==="W" ||
      y === 0 && direction==="S" ||
      max_x === x && direction==="E" ||
      max_y === y && direction==="N"
     ) {
      wallHit +=1;
     }
      return wallHit;
  } ```

Comment: You need to enclose the different logical paths in parentheses to make it more readable. `if (
  (x === 0 && direction === "W") ||
    (y === 0 && direction === "S") ||` etc - kind of how my answer puts the `||` and `&&`s together, and the linter should be happy.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
and compose a character string gathering all of your values:

```js
const roombaMovement = (direction , initialRoombaLocation, roomSize) =>
  {
  let wallHit = 0
    , testVal = `${JSON.stringify(initialRoombaLocation)} && "${direction}"`
    ;
  if (testVal==='[4,0] && "S"')
    {
    testVal += ` && ${JSON.stringify(roomSize)}`;
    }
  switch (testVal)
    {
    case '[4,0] && "S" && [4,0]':
    case '[1,0] && "S"': 
    case '[0,0] && "W"':
    case '[0,1] && "W"':
      ++wallHit;
      break;
    }
  return wallHit;
  }
```

which is gives a little more readable code ;)

Comment: @PierceF  be careful, my previous answer had a logic error ; I  corrected

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess at the actual intent of the code…

- Define what a wall is. For example:

  ```js
  const isWall = ([x, y], [roomWidth, roomHeight]) =>
    x === -1
    || y === -1
    || x === roomWidth + 1    // check which of roomWidth or roomWidth + 1 is correct
    || y === roomHeight + 1;  // same here
  ```
- Check whether the movement brings you into one:

  ```js
  const roombaMovement = (direction, initialRoombaLocation, roomSize) => {
    const [x, y] = initialRoombaLocation;
    const [dx, dy] = direction;
    const newLocation = [x + dx, y + dy];

    return isWall(newLocation, roomSize);
  };
  ```

Answer (score 0):

here are some pointers for you:

1. don't change the order of your parameters. (direction , initialRoombaLocation, roomSize) vs (roombaLocation && direction && roomSize). It's just better coding to be consistent.
2. There's no reason to assign a variable into another variable: `const roombaLocation = initialRoombaLocation`, just use initialRoombaLocation.
3. This is not valid syntax: `&& "S"`. maybe you meant: `&& direction == "S"`
4. `roombaLocation == [1, 0]` is not valid syntax. you will need to find a better was to check that condition.
5. There's no reason to use a case statement if there's only one possible result. just use a simple if statement.

good luck!